# How to inspect HTTP requests in Safari 8

Tags: safari

I can't seem to find a way to view the raw HTTP requests sent by safari to the webserver. Does anyone know how you can do this in Safari 8.

I did manage to find some HTTP headers in the resource tab of the web inspector [image] But I want to see the raw (in plain text) HTTP request

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this possible with 8/9 safari? real pain to debug